# How to test endpoint with Principal

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to test a GET endpoint with `@Context Principal principal` but this endpoint has this line of code in the beginning of the endpoint

`String principalName = UserUtils.getPrincipalName(principal);`

> ERROR: org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException: 401
> UNAUTHORIZED "Invalid user id"

This is a h2 test case with no data when I call the GET. How do I pass the principal into the endpoint?